# Disable GPS Backgroung Limits in Android

Tags: android, gps, limit

Thanks in advance for the help you will give me.
I am working on a project of my own and need to use many apps that require location access. I use version 7.1 of Android installed on Oracle VirtualBox.

At the moment I noticed that after about 26 apps requiring location access, forced to be active, the system stops sharing the location with other apps. I am not able to figure out how to get around this block, also because there is little information about the problem!

Does anyone have any info on how to get around the block?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Since giving permission is the users privilege you can't deny or revoke other apps to enable your app's. So you may ask the user to disable one of his Location granted apps politely by using Devices Location Setting , additionally by accessing  the list of apps that has the Location Permission and their respective usage statistics (how frequently the location is used in the app ) you may suggest the user to revoke or deny the least used app's permission ,the next step will be requesting permission for your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot Takele. I need to use all this app but i would use more apps that require GPS. So is possible disable this limit in Android?

Comment: i don't think  it is possible to remove the limit,may be if you can get the Permission of at least one app , then use ContentProviders or SharedPreferences so that you may not need Location Permission to all your apps.

Comment: Thank you, i will try!